# How do I prevent users from entering a blank value in an Excel sheet?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007, data-validation

I want to restrict users to entering either just 0 or 1 in an Excel 2007 sheet.

I use the Data > Data Validation dialog to do this, but I'm finding that it doesn't stop them from entering blanks.

What I would like is for there to be a prompt when they enter blanks, just like the one that appears when they enter any other non-blank data that is not 0 or 1.

I plan to fill the sheet with 0s **before** applying the validation, so there should not be a problem with erroneous data.

Also, I'm open to using VBA to fix this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This change event procedure will look at any cell that has validation and display the error message from the validation.  It doesn't work like validation in that it doesn't force a "retry".  Also, it sticks a '1' in there if it gets deleted.  You could put the old value in there, but it would take more work and it's generally something I try to avoid.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim sForm As String

    On Error Resume Next
        sForm = Target.Validation.Formula1
    On Error GoTo 0

    If Len(sForm) > 0 Then 'has validation
        If IsEmpty(Target.Value) Then 'cell was deleted
            MsgBox Target.Validation.ErrorMessage, vbOKOnly, Target.Validation.ErrorTitle
            Application.EnableEvents = False
                Target.Value = 1
            Application.EnableEvents = True
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks - this worked so well that I'm using it *instead* of my validation. :)

Answer (score 0):

There should be an option in the Data Validation settings to "Ignore blank". If you disable (uncheck) the option does that not do what you desire?

Set the DV to a Whole Number between 0 and 1 and uncheck "Ignore blank"

Comment: I tried that, but it doesn't work. I find that I can still enter blank data.